# Get the value of dropdown from parent with in a iframe using jQuery

Tags: jquery, iframe

I have a dropdown outside the iframe

```
<select id="ModuleDropDown">
     <option>Hello world</option>
</select>
```

and I have an iframe like this

```
 <iframe id="EditorFrame" src="UploadTemplates.aspx" frameborder="0" style="height: 900px;
            width: 1000px" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
```

the code of UploadTemplate.aspx is:

```
<asp:Button ID="UploadButton" runat="server" Text="Upload"" />
```

so now my question is that how can I get the value of dropdown in iframe using jQuery I tried this but it doesn't help me

```
$("#UploadButton").click(function () {
    alert($("#ModuleDropDown").val());
});
```

but when I click the button I got `undefined` instead of value of dropdown please help me

Comment: I do not believe you can, the browser will not let you.

Comment: If it on the same domain it can be done. So is it on the same domain? ;-)

Comment: here is a similar question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729577/can-javascript-access-iframe-elements-from-the-parent-page

Comment: see the accepts answer nothing is impossible dear

Comment: @HaseebKhan While I was mistaken, due to a misunderstanding of what you were asking, that by no means that "nothing is impossible".  Additionally the condescension is entirely unnecessary, and is in fact rude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this one will to the trick for you:

```
$("#UploadButton").click(function () {
    alert($("#ModuleDropDown", window.parent.document).val())
})
```

The extra argument tells jQuery in which context that should be used.

Comment: The code should be placed inside the iframe. When the button with ID UploadButton is clicked its seach for element with ID ModuleDropDown in the context of its parent.

Comment: please explain this if u can?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    $selectedValue=$("#EditorFrame").contents().find("select#ModuleDropDown").val();
    alert($selectedValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
$('#EditorFrame').contains().find("body").on("click", "#UploadButton", function(){
   alert($("#ModuleDropDown", window.parent.document).val());
});
```