# Accessing elements in the iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can javascript access iframe elements from the parent page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729577/can-javascript-access-iframe-elements-from-the-parent-page)

I have an iframe in my document, and I want to get (and change) some attributes in it with JQuery. This is the code:

```
var iframe = $('iframe');

        $("#id").click(function() {
            var btn = iframe.contents().find('a[href*="script.php"]'); 
            alert(btn);
            for (var i=0, attrs=btn.attributes, l=attrs.length; i<l; i++){
                alert(attrs.item(i).nodeName);
            }
         });
```

The first alert says "[object Object]", then I'm getting errors:

> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL
>   http://somedomain.ru/somescript.php from frame with URL
>   http://domain.wia-games.net/. Domains, protocols and ports must match.

and

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

How should I solve the problem?

UPD.
console.log(btn):

> [prevObject: st.fn.st.init[0], context: document, selector:
>   "a[href*="script.php"]", jquery: "1.9.0", constructor: function…]
>   context: #document length: 0 prevObject: st.fn.st.init[0] selector:
>   "a[href*="script.php"]"
>   **proto**: Object[0]

Comment: You can't change the contents of an iframe from another domain

Comment: Ok, if I can not change some attribute, how can I read it's value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a constraint implemented on browsers for security reasons: [**Same origin policy**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Safe Workarounds exist:

- [JSON to JSONP: Bypass Same-Origin Policy](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42641/JSON-to-JSONP-Bypass-Same-Origin-Policy)
- Using headers: [Content Security Policy 1.1](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/content-security-policy/raw-file/tip/csp-specification.dev.html)
- [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/) ?!

Answer (score 1):

Most Browsers as a security feature prohibit Cross Site Scripting:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

That means the two Objects must have the same source domain.

As a workaround you might want to query the foreign page on the server-side (e.g. with php)