# Trying to get a div from within an iframe then place it inside a div on my own website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am trying to extract a particular div called '.tutintro' from the website, http://www.w3schools.com/js/, which is inside a hidden iframe. Then, place it into a div called '#test' on my website.

Here's all the code that I believe will allow me to do this, but I cant seem to edit it to get the div content onto my page.

The HTML:

```
<iframe style="display:none;" id="iframe" scrolling="no" src="http://www.w3schools.com/js/" style="border: 0px none; margin-left: -295px; height: 450px; margin-top: -120px; width: 1300px;"></iframe>

<div id="test"></div>
```

The Javascript:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('#iframe');
var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
var text = .innerDoc.getElementById('.tutintro');
var output = document.getElementById('test');

output.innerHTML = text;
```

Comment: You have a syntax error text = .inner should be text = inner

Comment: you cannot access content from cross domain iframe like this

Comment: A. Wolff - Is there any other way to do this, even if it means getting rid of the iframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sir you can't handle the content of IFram, (browser security) 
check [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729577/can-javascript-access-iframe-elements-from-the-parent-page)

Answer (score 0):

1) A div "called" ".tutintro" doesn't appear to be an id, so calling getElementById for it will never get you what you're looking for.

2) The parent window doesn't have access to the DOM of the child window if it's on a different domain / you don't have control over the page - see this for more info - [Access child iFrame DOM from parent page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181911/access-child-iframe-dom-from-parent-page)