# get iframe query string with javaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have an iframe. When the page loads, the page makes a queryString.

I need to access the query string that is generated after the page is loaded

But with this code just I can access the src without the query string

```
alert(document.getElementById('myframe').src);
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729577/can-javascript-access-iframe-elements-from-the-parent-page

Comment: my parent url : localhost/web_social
and my iframe url : localhost:8585/something

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
document.getElementById("myframe").contentWindow.location.href
```

where **myframe** is the id of the frame

Comment: get this errror in console :
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'myframe' of undefined htmlpage.html:121getiframeURL htmlpage.html:121onclick htmlpage.html:130

screanshot : http://www.xum.ir/image/bLMC

Comment: works for me, try this: `alert(document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].contentWindow.location.href);`