# I need to access one specific element inside iframe video?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to access the play button of a vimeo video in my page. Since it's an iframe, I am not able to get the play button using jquery.

Here is the code that tried:

```
$(".component.video.detail").on("click", ".vp-controls > button", function () {
    alert("triggered play button");
});
```

also this didn't work:

```
$(document).on("click", ".vp-controls > button", alert("triggered play button"));
```

Any help or insights will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can javascript access iframe elements from the parent page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729577/can-javascript-access-iframe-elements-from-the-parent-page)

Comment: That post answers only to Can I, I need help with how can I?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you have to access the document of the iFrame and then search for the element in there.

```
const iFrame = document.getElementById('iFrameID');
const innerDocument = iFrame.contentDocument || iFrame.contentWindow.document;
```

As per MattSizzle's link, this only works within the same domain. Since this is an external Vimeo video, you will not be able to access its internals since cross-site scripting is a security violation.